# Excel VBA to Paste Formula to Variable Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to create a VBA code that will paste a formula to Variable Range of both columns and cells.  I have the start of a code I thought I could modify, but I have been unsuccessful.

I have a sheet (see image) that has a variable range between A2 & ?  I need to paste into the area C3 to the end of rows and columns a formula that will take the value in B and divide it by the number of columns.  I thought I had a start but I am failing.

Please assist.  "Start" Code Follows

```
Sub QtyByWks()
    Dim M As Long, N As Long, i As Long, x As Long, j As Long
    M = Sheet10.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    N = Sheet10.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 3
    For x = 1 To M
        For i = 1 To N
            If Cells(i, "B").Value > 0 Then
                Cells(j, "C").Value = Cells(i, "B").Value
                j = j + 2
            End If
        Next i
    Next x
End Sub
```

Also note, Both Rows and Columns are Variable via an additional VBA [Capture of Worksheet]

Thanks in advance for the assist

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG6YN.png]

Comment: I got an alert saying image to post after review?

Comment: Can you give an illustration of your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell what sort of errors/issues you had with your code since you haven't provided much info.  Either way, I'll take a stab at adjusting what you provided to do what I THINK you're trying to do:

```
Sub QtyByWks()
    Dim M As Long, N As Long, i As Long, x As Long, j As Long
' Changed the formula to check row 2 instead of one, as per your screenshot.
    M = Sheet1.Cells(2, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    N = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 3
'Replaced the x loop with a j loop that increments by 2.  
    For j = 3 To N Step 2
'Had the i loop start from 3 instead of 1
        For i = 3 To M
            If Cells(j, "B").Value > 0 Then
'Divided the "B" value by the number of columns M, which is what it sounds like you were going for in your description.
                Cells(j, i).Value = Cells(j, "B").Value / (M - 2)
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Obviously the code is working on the assumption that the Columns and Rows variables are returning expected values.

Comment: PERFECT!  I thought my question was clear, sorry.  But you nailed it.  Help me out here if you will?  Why the "j" loop versus the "x" loop?  And why start the "i" loop from 3 versus 1?

Comment: You weren't using the x anywhere.  You were using j for rows, and i for...  well, it's hard to tell.  But x wasn't being used anywhere.  And then, I set the i loop to start from 3 and go to M, because that is the range of columns you want to fill, between C (column #3) and M.  If we started from i = 1, you would overwrite columns A and B.